# Count # of Weeks (Summary Level) and show on grant summary level

Tags: reporting

I have a report that has time entry records.  Each week is a summary level, so I can sum total time worked for each week.  I'm wondering if there is any way to count the number of summary rows (the number of weeks) and display on the grant summary row.  (Ultimately I want to calculate time worked per week on the grand summary so I would sum time and divide by # of weeks).

I've tried using a "power of one" type formula, but that seems to only count the records, not the weeks (below # of weeks is a formula field with value always equal to 1).  In my photo below, I'd like to have the sum of the weeks appear in the grand total, "4".

In the image below, "end of week" is a formula field which calculates the last day of the work week given a specific date.  Ultimately I need the number of weeks in the grand summary, so I can begin to do average per week calculations for the records, given a particular date range that could be changing.  I've tried using custom summary formulas (Sum: # of Weeks) but of course that gives me the total number of records rather than the number of weeks.

[image]

Comment: can you provide the field details and custom summary formula which you have tried so far

Comment: I've added the information to the post per Santanu's request.  If additional info. is needed, let me know.